# Validation framework for .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: validation, compact-framework

Do you know of a fast and simple entity validation framework that could be used in a Compact Framework project?

I've done some experiments with [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) (using [db4o System.Linq.Expressions](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2008/09/22/linq-expression-trees-on-the-compact-framework), but it's rather slow) and [EViL](http://evil.codeplex.com/) (but it seems a bit half-baked).

Can you suggest any other or maybe point me to some resources on how to design such a framework so that it's both easy to use and performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Legend framework](http://legend.codeplex.com) has a lightweight set of fluent validation extensions (in Legend.Core.Tests).  I've not done any perf experiments on it, but it's at least another data point you could look at.